# Why scale down/up pods horizontally within node on cloud platform?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, azure-aks

I am new to K8s. I am researching benefits of using k8s on GKE/AKS over Azure VM Scalesets used in our system.

For k8s, let's say we deploy worker application to 5 nodes cluster, each node can runs 10 pods. Each node is 16 core, 64G memory VM.

My question is, since we are paying cloud service provider by node, not by pod, why we want to scale down pod on the node at all?

Does it make more sense to horizontally scale up and down nodes only, while having maximum pods on each node?

Does 10 pods, 20 pods, 30 pods, 40 pods, 50 pods makes more sense, meanwhile 11 pods, 21 pods, 31 pods, 41 pods etc sounds wasting resources we paid?

I must missed key points of doing pods scaling.
Please point them out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your pods are all identical, then yes, it likely makes sense to scale them only in node-sized equivalents (but maybe in that case you want to actually make sure the nodes can scale in increments that make sense to your workload size -- e.g. do you really need another 32 or 64 or 96 cores worth of your application every time?  This is one of the things that the new Google [batch for Kubernetes](https://cloud.google.com/batch/) product tries to address -- including rightsizing of machines).

But think if you have a heterogeneous set of workloads (far more likely with k8s!) -- then one of the advantages of k8s is that you can binpack different workloads onto the same node.

Imagine if one workload needs a lot of RAM, but not much CPU, and another workload needs a lot of CPU and not a lot of RAM -- you wouldn't want them to both scale up in one-node increments, you'd want the pods to scale with the demands on each application, and the nodes to scale when you can no longer binpack onto the existing machines.

Comment: Thanks for introducing batch on GKE for me.

Comment: You're welcome.  Of course, AFAIT, it was literally launched to beta in the last few days, so I don't know much about it :)

Comment: For the scenario multiple applications consume resources differently.
If use multiple clusters for different applications, cluster scales on node only, each node runs one pod. Node size determined by minimum to fit application requirement.
How does "different workloads onto the same node" wins over this strategy on cloud platform?

Comment: You're missing something very powerful about kubernetes -- don't think about the 1-2 application case, think about the hundreds or even thousands of application case.  Do you really want to maintain hundreds or thousands of clusters?  Do _all_ of those applications binpack in exact multiples of machines?  Do they keep scaling that way forever?  Beyond even a small scale, the answer is likely to be no.  And, even though you could use custom machine types on GCE, they are more expensive per core to scale incrementally that way.

Comment: I was thinking at team's perspective. We are maintaining less than 20 services. 
We pushed some services to Azure cloud and running about 10 VM Scalesets, just like 10 clusters.
The VM Scalesets management effort is minimum. 
I wasn't thought about push all services to cloud and how to manage them.

I have to play with k8s more on gke/aks, to see how it help on improving scaling performance and reduce cost.

I have accepted this answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Because it is easier to think in terms of scaling policies for a single deployment at a time.
2. Because you can set the system to collapse low utilization nodes together and then delete unused nodes.
3. Because it gives you better stats to track your utilization rate.